# Able to Toggle to Full Screen in a MAP but not able to minimize it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Able to Toggle to Full Screen in a MAP but not able to minimize it

This is my Xpath for both Maximize and Min :

```
WebElement togglefullscreen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@title,'Toggle fullscreen view') and contains(@style,'position: absolute')]/img[1]"));
//maximizing the map
builder.moveToElement(togglefullscreen).click().perform();


//minimizing the Map
builder.moveToElement(togglefullscreen).click().perform(); = this is the place where it is not minimizing...
```

My Map is similar to the Map given in the link where the [click here](http://beta.findtoilet.dk/?term=2&lat=55.678937&lng=12.575738&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap)

```
HTML: -<button draggable="false" aria-label="Toggle fullscreen view" title="Toggle fullscreen view" type="button" class="gm-control-active gm-fullscreen-control" style="background: none rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; text-transform: none; appearance: none; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; user-select: none; border-radius: 2px; height: 40px; width: 40px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; right: 0px;"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2018%2018%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%20d%3D%22M0%200v6h2V2h4V0H0zm16%200h-4v2h4v4h2V0h-2zm0%2016h-4v2h6v-6h-2v4zM2%2012H0v6h6v-2H2v-4z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E" alt="" style="height: 18px; width: 18px;"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2018%2018%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23333%22%20d%3D%22M0%200v6h2V2h4V0H0zm16%200h-4v2h4v4h2V0h-2zm0%2016h-4v2h6v-6h-2v4zM2%2012H0v6h6v-2H2v-4z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E" alt="" style="height: 18px; width: 18px;"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2018%2018%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23111%22%20d%3D%22M0%200v6h2V2h4V0H0zm16%200h-4v2h4v4h2V0h-2zm0%2016h-4v2h6v-6h-2v4zM2%2012H0v6h6v-2H2v-4z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E" alt="" style="height: 18px; width: 18px;"></button>
```

Any  leads on this ...

Comment: What do you mean by minimizing the map ?

Comment: When you click on toggle full screen the map appears in full screen and then we need to minimize it hope its is clear the link given in the question hsa the toggle full screen button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all it needs is basically an explicit waits in combination with worst explicit wait which is  `Thread.sleep(4000);`. to the above mentioned link, I could do maximize and minimize by using the below code :-

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://beta.findtoilet.dk/?term=2&lat=55.678937&lng=12.575738&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
Thread.sleep(4000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class*='gm-fullscreen']"))).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class*='gm-fullscreen']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see clicking on this element toggles the view from regular view to maximized and vice versa.
I guess you should put delay between clicking this button first time and the second click to make the window stabilize in the new size, to be ready to change to another size.
BTW the correct locator here is

```
WebElement togglefullscreen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@title,'Toggle fullscreen view') and contains(@style,'position: absolute')]"));
```

the button itself, not the `img` element there.